# How to generate Custom ID

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a custom value for the ID. For example, it will start with "CR00001" and after that it will increment the numerical portion (e.g. CR00002) when I save the data for the second time.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 Dim cr_id As String
 cr_id = "CR00001"
 Dim iReturn As Boolean

 Using SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)
     Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()
         sqlCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
         With sqlCommand
             .CommandText = "INSERT INTO cr_record(idcr_record,Emplid,isu,Nama,date1,DeptDesc,email,change1,reasonchange,problem,priority,reasondescription,systemrequest,attachment) VALUES (@cr_id,@Emplid,@isu,@Nama,@date1,@DeptDesc,@email,@change1,@reasonchange,@problem,@priority,@reasondescription,@systemrequest,@attachment)"
             .CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
             .CommandTimeout = 5000
             .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cr_id", cr_id)
```

Comment: whenever you are about to insert, you shall select the latest id from database table (u'll need a datetime or time column in SQL table), then add your VB.Net logic to increment it, some thing like: string sql="Select idcr_record from cr_record order by addedon DESC"; then obtain its value and check the leading zeros using substring or string.index of functions, then use a switch statement to add 1 into id.

Comment: If at all possible, just keep plain integers as your ID numbers in your database, and make turning a plain integer into a string that starts `CR` and then pads that integer out to 5 digits as a function that you just apply when you're *displaying* the IDs to users.

Comment: SALAM @UsmanWaheed i using mysql table. but not concern about it. The ID field i using varchar(10). auto,notnull. i dont understand about you saying .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i use varchar for ID COLUMN . how can i do  that. im just blur..

Comment: And I'm asking, why not simply store IDs *in the database* as 1, 2, 3, etc. And when it comes time to *display* these IDs to the users, you can do `String.Format("CR{0:00000}",ID)`. Unless you have a strong reason to, don't store data in the database as *strings* just so that you can apply some kind of formatting. Keep formatting (and, if necessary, parsing) in the front end and keep the data in the database in its most natural form.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks i will try it i found about this but.. when i use it just display only 1 without CR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to generate a new ID, write one function for generating the ID, and copy this code there. Keep the return type as `String` to return `newId`.

```
    Dim newId As String
    Dim stringId As String
    Dim intId As Integer
    Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your database query string")
    Dim adpt As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select id from tableName Where date = (SELECT max(date) from tableName)", conn) 'Where tableName is you table
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    adpt.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then 'This will check whether any records are there or not
        newId = "CR00001" ' If records are not there then this id will be returned
    Else
        stringId = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString    'This will store your id in string format
        intId = stringId.Substring(2)       ' This will store only integer values from that id
        intId += 1      ' Increment id by 1
        newId = String.Concat("CR", intId)      ' Creating new Id incremented by 1
    End If
    Return newId
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add some sample code explaining your solution.

Comment: @sarjit Delivala thanks for explaination but seem i dont understand the code .. can you give example of it

Comment: @RyanKohn im truely aggreed with u put some sample code for explaination

Comment: @RyanKohn i have try it..tq for solution ;)