# how to generate custom id using year and integer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I want to make a custom ID Number using year and integer. 
This is my code:

```
    Dim idnumber As Integer
    Dim yrVal As String = DateTime.Now.Year
    idnumber = yrVal + "0001"

    textboxIDNumber.Text = idnumber

    Connection()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Info WHERE idnumber LIKE '" & textboxIDNumber.Text & "'"
    rs.Open(sql, conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic) 
    If rs.Fields(0).Value <> idnumber Then 
        rs.AddNew()
        rs.Fields(0).Value = textboxIDNumber.Text
        rs.Fields(1).Value = textboxLastName.Text
        rs.Fields(2).Value = textboxFirstName.Text
        rs.Fields(3).Value = textboxMiddleName.Text
        rs.Update()
        MsgBox("Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
    Else
        If rs.Fields(0).Value = idnumber Then
            rs.AddNew()
            textboxIDNumber.Text += 1
            rs.Fields(0).Value = textboxIDNumber.Text
            rs.Fields(1).Value = textboxLastName.Text
            rs.Fields(2).Value = textboxFirstName.Text
            rs.Fields(3).Value = textboxMiddleName.Text
            rs.Update()
            MsgBox("Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
        End If
    End If
        conn.Close()
```

I want to add an auto generated id number of a certain individual using YEAR and 4 digit integer to be exact.

```
    Dim idnumber As Integer
    Dim yrVal As String = DateTime.Now.Year
    idnumber = yrVal + "0001"
```

What I want is that if I register a person for the first time then his/her id number is 20180001 and the second person is 20180002, 0003, 004 and so on, but when the year is 2019 then it start again with 20190001, 20190002, 20190003 and so on. In my code as shown above it will increment from 20180001 to 20189999. I'm a beginner to this and it's hard to figure out.

[How to generate Custom ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706830/how-to-generate-custom-id)

I tried the solution link above but It is using OLeDBAdapter, dataset, datagrid and I don't know how to convert it to ADODB. I added ADODB reference. I'm a beginner and a little bit confused.

Comment: The code in your question is not ado.net, it's just ado (the previous version), meaning it's probably not even vb.net but either vb6 or vbscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy... For the first time, generate an id with the below code :

```
Dim idnumber As Integer
Dim yrVal As String = DateTime.Now.Year
idnumber = yrVal + "0001"

''''Insert the data, I am not adding the inserting code :)
```

Now,in order to generate the 2nd id, we need to first get the last id we inserted into the database. For that, use the below code :

```
Dim LastId as Integer
Dim FirstIdCmd as New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName ORDER BY ID DESC",connection) 'Here ID is the column name and DESC stands for descending
Dim dr as SqlDataReader = FirstIdCmd.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read
 '''Here we get the last generated I
 Dim lstId as String = dr(0).ToString.Substring(4, 4)
End While
```

Now focus on the line **dr(0).ToString.Substring(4,4)**. `Strng.Substring` method is used to extract a specific part of a string. The method accepts 2 integer variable value. The first one is the `StartingIndex` and the last one is the `Length`. As we need to get only the last 3 digits of the ID and need to bypass the first 4 digits, we set `StartIndex` to 4 and `Length` to 4. So, let's get back to coding again :

```
While dr.Read
''Here,instead of creating a new string variable, we pass the value(with +1) to the declared Integer variable called LastID
 LastId = Convert.ToInt32(dr(0).ToString.Substring(4, 4)) + 1
End While
```

Now you can use the ID and insert it. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've use your solution and it suggested to import System.Data.SqlClient in order to use SqlDataReader and SqlCommand. When I tried to run ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized. I doubt if this command get the last record save in the database and add it with 1.

Comment: 1. add these lines on the top level of your entire code : `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` | 2. What is connection ? It has to be your sqlConnection , example : `Dim connection as new SqlConnection("connection string here")`

Comment: By the way, I'm using Module.

Public conn As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public sql As String

Public Function Connection()
        conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\SystemDatabase.mdb"
        conn.Open()
        Return Nothing
    End Function

Comment: so your connection variable name is `conn` ? use `conn` then

Comment: It only said ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized. I don't know why, I've import `System.Data.SqlClient`, I also use conn. https://imgur.com/a/3wL2buS

Comment: Did you use `conn.Open` ? you need to open the connection first

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170412/discussion-between-j-leo-and-zack-raiyan).

Comment: As soon as you get more than one user of the application your method of getting the last id is flawed.

Comment: Because of race conditions. Two or more users could generate the same id if they are working at the same time. I don't know if MS Access has such features, but that is what a SEQUENCE is for in MS SQL Server.

Comment: firstly ,it's not sql , and I am preety sure that won't actually happen .. I mean , if that is the case, there's no way around :(

Comment: "sql" is a generic term, so it is sql. Your example is using the MS SQL Server provider but OP is clearly not using MS SQL Server, so that's another problem. And what you have done is a very well established anti-pattern, I am actually very sure it would happen. There are always other ways.

Comment: @Crowcoder , it's not sql .. I know my answer answer seems to be like sql but the OP's db  isn't in sql

Comment: You can't use those libraries on MS Access so unless OP is going to move the database from Access to MS SQL Server ("sql" alone does not mean MS SQL Server) then adding those references will not not help.

Comment: @zackraiyan Thank you so much! You helped me a lot. You solved my problem. I will never forget what you've have done.

Comment: @J.Leo , as i said , sharing knowledge is my pleasure :)